# Automatic analysis Sonar Qube how to setup?

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've set up a SonarQube server, also I use the default sonar-scanner 2.5 version to scan my C# and JS files. I've successfully created the projects and can view them in sonar qube admin panel.

Now my question is I've seen in the documentation the following:

http://docs.sonarqube.org/download/attachments/6951178/SQ52Integration.png?version=1&modificationDate=1445455530000&api=v2

It says "Automatic Build + Code Analysis" Im using SVN and I have no idea how to automatically run Sonar Qube when I commit code changes? I use VS 2012 and it has an old plugin for sonar which is kinda confusing and I want to avoid using it.

Can someone please elaborate or point me to the place in the documentation on how to set up automatic code analysis for C# and JS mostly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a Continuous Integration server? This would typically be the place that runs the SonarQube analysis.

For C# projects, the analysis is done with the "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild":
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

If you don't have a CI server you could also start the analysis from a Subversion hook script, but that would be a rather unusual setup (and would only work if time between two commits is longer than it takes for the analysis to run)

Comment: With Continuous Integration Server you mean Something like Jenkins?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Something like Jenkins, TFS, CruiseControl.Net, etc.